# Min Height for a Row which can be collapsed in some scenario

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have a grid with multiple rows. out of which some of the rows can be collapsed in some particular scenario. Is there a way to define min height for these collapsible rows so that there height matches the other rows?

Thanks

Comment: So you want collapsed rows to have a minimum height instead of collapsing it entirely ?

Comment: Let me explain to make it more clear. Rows which are not collapsible have minimum height. What i want is when the collapsible rows are not collapsed these should have same height as of other rows. And when collapsed then of course they should be fully collapsed.